# How to post data to drupal commerce services?

Tags: php, web-services, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-commerce

I'm uses [Drupal commerce services](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_services) for mobile commerce. But I don't know how to Post jSON to REST service Cart or Order.
With Comment services I"m post JSON successful as below:

```
URL: [http://myserver.com/services/comment/][1]
METHOD: POST
JSON BODY:
{
    "comment":{
      "comment_body":{
        "und":[
          {"value":"Good job"}
        ]
      },
      "nid":"23",
      "subject":"Drupal Services Comment"
    }
}
```

I don't know what is JSON Body to POST to Cart or Order Service like that? Anyone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found JSON structure for Cart or Order Services. It's something as below:

```
{
   "type":"commerce_order",
   "commerce_customer_billing":"10",
   "commerce_line_items":
       [
           "11",
           "13",
           "14",
           "15",
           "16"
       ]
}
```

Comment: Where did you found that structure? It's working for me :)

What if I want to specify a new line item? Need to send a JSON type line item and send it via POST message or can I specify it as value for commerce_line_items item, like this:

{
"commerce_line_items": [
    {
        "11": {
            "key": "value"
        }
    },
    "13",
    "14",
    "15",
    "16"
    ]
}